# Airflow duplicates content of the logs while writing to GCS

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow

I configured Airflow 1.9 to store dag logs in Google Cloud Storage following (exactly) [this description](https://airflow.apache.org/howto/write-logs.html#writing-logs-to-google-cloud-storage). It is working, however parts of the content of all DAGs logs seems to be duplicated (see below). It appears as if the log were appended to itself with additional information about the upload. The log file on a local drive doesn't have those duplicates.

It seems that [gcs_write](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/a592e732356427b4fd1ed27c890cf82e9cf495f0/airflow/utils/log/gcs_task_handler.py#L144) is by default using an append mode - so the only hack I found is to change it to False. Is there a configuration for that? What is the reason for this anyway?

I have changed following variables in the cfg file:

```
task_log_reader=gcs.task
logging_config_class=log_config.LOGGING_CONFIG
remote_log_conn_id=gcs
```

log_config.py:

```
GCS_LOG_FOLDER = 'gs://XXXX/'

LOG_LEVEL = conf.get('core', 'LOGGING_LEVEL').upper()
LOG_FORMAT = conf.get('core', 'log_format')

BASE_LOG_FOLDER = conf.get('core', 'BASE_LOG_FOLDER')
PROCESSOR_LOG_FOLDER = conf.get('scheduler', 'child_process_log_directory')

FILENAME_TEMPLATE = '{{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ try_number }}.log'
PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE = '{{ filename }}.log'

LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'airflow.task': {
            'format': LOG_FORMAT,
        },
        'airflow.processor': {
            'format': LOG_FORMAT,
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.task',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'
        },
        'file.task': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.file_task_handler.FileTaskHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.task',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
            'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        },
        'file.processor': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.file_processor_handler.FileProcessorHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.processor',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(PROCESSOR_LOG_FOLDER),
            'filename_template': PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        }
        , 'gcs.task': {
             'class': 'airflow.utils.log.gcs_task_handler.GCSTaskHandler',
             'formatter': 'airflow.task',
             'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
             'gcs_log_folder': GCS_LOG_FOLDER,
             'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
         },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL
        },
        'airflow': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'airflow.processor': {
            'handlers': ['file.processor'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'airflow.task': {
            'handlers': ['gcs.task'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'airflow.task_runner': {
            'handlers': ['gcs.task'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Log:

```
*** Reading remote log from gs://XXXX/mwt1/mwt1_task1/2018-10-02T15:30:00/1.log.
[2018-11-16 10:27:17,304] {{cli.py:374}} INFO - Running on host fdfdf2f790e1
[2018-11-16 10:27:17,336] {{models.py:1197}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: mwt1.mwt1_task1 2018-10-02 15:30:00 [queued]>
[2018-11-16 10:27:17,342] {{models.py:1197}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: mwt1.mwt1_task1 2018-10-02 15:30:00 [queued]>
[2018-11-16 10:27:17,342] {{models.py:1407}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting attempt 1 of 4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2018-11-16 10:27:17,354] {{models.py:1428}} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): mwt1_task1> on 2018-10-02 15:30:00
[2018-11-16 10:27:17,355] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', 'airflow run mwt1 mwt1_task1 2018-10-02T15:30:00 --job_id 48 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/mwt1.py']
[2018-11-16 10:27:17,939] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:17,938] {{__init__.py:45}} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,231] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,230] {{models.py:189}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/mwt1.py
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,451] {{cli.py:374}} INFO - Running on host fdfdf2f790e1
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,473] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,473] {{bash_operator.py:70}} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,473] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:  /tmp
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,474] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,473] {{bash_operator.py:80}} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmp5g0d6e4h//tmp/airflowtmp5g0d6e4h/mwt1_task1_8ob3n0y
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,474] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,473] {{bash_operator.py:88}} INFO - Running command: bdasdasdasd
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,479] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,479] {{bash_operator.py:97}} INFO - Output:
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,479] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,479] {{bash_operator.py:101}} INFO - /tmp/airflowtmp5g0d6e4h/mwt1_task1_8ob3n0y: line 1: bdasdasdasd: command not found
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,480] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,480] {{bash_operator.py:105}} INFO - Command exited with return code 127
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,488] {{models.py:1595}} ERROR - Bash command failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1493, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 109, in execute
    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,490] {{models.py:1616}} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,503] {{models.py:1644}} ERROR - Bash command failed

[2018-11-16 10:27:17,304] {{cli.py:374}} INFO - Running on host fdfdf2f790e1
[2018-11-16 10:27:17,336] {{models.py:1197}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: mwt1.mwt1_task1 2018-10-02 15:30:00 [queued]>
[2018-11-16 10:27:17,342] {{models.py:1197}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: mwt1.mwt1_task1 2018-10-02 15:30:00 [queued]>
[2018-11-16 10:27:17,342] {{models.py:1407}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting attempt 1 of 4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2018-11-16 10:27:17,354] {{models.py:1428}} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): mwt1_task1> on 2018-10-02 15:30:00
[2018-11-16 10:27:17,355] {{base_task_runner.py:115}} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', 'airflow run mwt1 mwt1_task1 2018-10-02T15:30:00 --job_id 48 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/mwt1.py']
[2018-11-16 10:27:17,939] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:17,938] {{__init__.py:45}} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,231] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,230] {{models.py:189}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags/mwt1.py
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,451] {{cli.py:374}} INFO - Running on host fdfdf2f790e1
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,473] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,473] {{bash_operator.py:70}} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,473] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:  /tmp
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,474] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,473] {{bash_operator.py:80}} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmp5g0d6e4h//tmp/airflowtmp5g0d6e4h/mwt1_task1_8ob3n0y
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,474] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,473] {{bash_operator.py:88}} INFO - Running command: bdasdasdasd
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,479] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,479] {{bash_operator.py:97}} INFO - Output:
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,479] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,479] {{bash_operator.py:101}} INFO - /tmp/airflowtmp5g0d6e4h/mwt1_task1_8ob3n0y: line 1: bdasdasdasd: command not found
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,480] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,480] {{bash_operator.py:105}} INFO - Command exited with return code 127
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,488] {{models.py:1595}} ERROR - Bash command failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1493, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 109, in execute
    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,490] {{models.py:1616}} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,503] {{models.py:1644}} ERROR - Bash command failed
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,504] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,504] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:   """)
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,504] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,504] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,504] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:     args.func(args)
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,505] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 392, in run
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,505] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:     pool=args.pool,
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,505] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 50, in wrapper
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,505] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,505] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1493, in _run_raw_task
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,505] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,505] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 109, in execute
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,506] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask:     raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,506] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,515] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,515] {{gcp_api_base_hook.py:82}} INFO - Getting connection using a JSON key file.
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,535] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,535] {{discovery.py:852}} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/XXXX/o/mwt1%2Fmwt1_task1%2F2018-10-02T15%3A30%3A00%2F1.log?alt=media
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,535] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,535] {{client.py:595}} INFO - Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,537] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,537] {{client.py:893}} INFO - Refreshing access_token
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,911] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,911] {{gcp_api_base_hook.py:82}} INFO - Getting connection using a JSON key file.
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,922] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,922] {{util.py:134}} WARNING - __init__() takes at most 2 positional arguments (3 given)
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,928] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,928] {{discovery.py:852}} INFO - URL being requested: POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/XXXX/o?name=mwt1%2Fmwt1_task1%2F2018-10-02T15%3A30%3A00%2F1.log&alt=json&uploadType=media
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,928] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,928] {{client.py:595}} INFO - Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
[2018-11-16 10:27:18,930] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: [2018-11-16 10:27:18,930] {{client.py:893}} INFO - Refreshing access_token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that affects both GCS and S3 remote logging, see [AIRFLOW-1916](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1916). It is fixed in Airflow 1.10 so you can either upgrade or pull run a fork with the [fix](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2880).

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Some how I overlooked that. It seems it is yet another reason to move to 1.10.